# Running 22.04 ARM as a VM in Parallels but no network connection is shown

Tags: networking, 22.04, arm

First I do have network connectivity and internet access...however, no network connection is shown under settings, network. How do I fix this?

Also, might be related...looks like snap-store GUI is not installed in 22.04 ARM, I manually installed it in terminal but when clicking update tab it says no connection. There is a button for network settings but it does nothing. Seems related.